# open a python program from other python program using subprocess

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess

I am trying to open a python program from other program in its directory and I get a message that says I dont have premission to do that.

```
import os
import subprocess
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
subprocess.call([str(path),'semi_server.py'])
```

and yes ive opened pycharm as an administrator

error message : WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied

can someone tell me what I did wronge?

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is to place the script from your first program in the same folder as the new program

```
path = 'script1'
```

Comment: they are in the same folder